# Formatar data em ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data

Possuo uma ViewBag retornando duas datas em um DropDown, porém elas estão retornando com a mesma formatação que foram salvas no banco( MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss). Necessito que elas retornem no padrão(dd/MM/yyyy).

Minha ViewBag está assim:

```
 ViewBag.Ferias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao != null)
               .Select(x => x.DtInicioPeriodo + " à " + x.DtFimPeriodo);
```

E em minha view, eu chamo ela deste modo:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Ferias", new SelectList(ViewBag.Ferias, "Ferias"))
```

O resultado é esse:

> Jun 22 2010 12:00AM à Feb 19 2014 12:00AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui separando os dois atributos, e concatenando eles na view.
Ficou assim:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Ferias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao == null)
            .Select(x => x.DtInicioPeriodo).ToList();
            ViewBag.FimFerias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao == null)
            .Select(x => x.DtFimPeriodo).ToList();
```

View:

```
<select>
                                @foreach (var date in ViewBag.Ferias)
                                {
                                    foreach (var fim in ViewBag.FimFerias) { 
                                    <option>
                                        @Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToShortDateString() à @Convert.ToDateTime(fim).ToShortDateString()
                                    </option>
                                    }
                                }
```

Se alguém possuir uma alternativa melhor, por favor poste aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Caso os dados sejam do tipo nullable e algum argumento possa ter um valor nulo:

Ficaria assim:

```
ViewBag.Ferias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao != null)
           .Select(x => 
            x.DtInicioPeriodo.HasValue ? x.Value.DtInicioPeriodo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "" 
             + " à " + 
            x.DtFimPeriodo.HasValue ? x.Value.DtFimPeriodo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "");
```

Comment: já tentei, mas recebo o seguinte erro:
"No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Tenta chamando um `.ToList()`, veja se isso funciona:
`ViewBag.Ferias = funcionarioFeriasRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matricula && r.SqContrato == contrato && r.DtInicioConcessao != null).ToList().Select(x => x.DtInicioPeriodo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " à " + x.DtFimPeriodo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`

Comment: Recebo o mesmo erro, com o .ToList()

Comment: Humm, o tipo `DtInicioPeriodo` é `DateTime` ou `string`?

Comment: os dois campos sao do tipo DateTime

Comment: Aparentemente o tipo não é `DateTime`, talvez `DateTime?` (nullable)?. Tenta agora, da forma que alterei a resposta.

Comment: Recebo esse erro agora:
does not contain a definition for value and no extension method value accepting a first argument of type could be found(are you missing using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: Os dados são DateTime? (nullable) sim

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta novamente, veja se é isso.

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo erro:  does not contain a definition for value and no extension method value accepting a first argument of type could be found(are you missing using directive or an assembly reference)